# how to make a table span 2 pages?

Tags: longtable, tabularx, tabu

i'm not an expert in Latex, Maybe the question seems straightforward for many of you.
I'm trying to make a table span 2 pages .

this is my code :

```
   \usepackage{tabu}
 \usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{array, tabularx, multirow}%

\definecolor{tableHeader}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}
\definecolor{tableLineOne}{RGB}{245, 245, 245}
\definecolor{tableLineTwo}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}

 \newcommand{\tableHeaderStyle}{
\rowfont{\leavevmode\color{white}\bfseries}
\rowcolor{tableHeader}
}

 \begin{document}
  \begin{center}
 \captionof{table}{Scénario d'authentification }
 \taburowcolors[2] 2{tableLineOne .. tableLineTwo}
 \tabulinesep = ^4mm_3mm
 \everyrow{\tabucline[.4mm  white]{}}
 \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {l >{\bfseries}X[r, 1] X[4] l}

    \tableHeaderStyle
    & Titre  & S'authentifier & \\
    & \textbf{But} & Sécuriser l’accès à l’application &\\

   & \textbf{Acteurs} & Tous les acteurs&\\
   &\textbf{Résumé} &Pour pouvoir se connecter à l’application, les   utilisateurs doivent s’authentifier à l’aide d’un identifiant et d’un mot de passe.
 Chaque utilisateur ne peut accéder qu’à sa session.&
 \\
   & \textbf{Pré condition(s)} & Les acteurs ont déjà un compte utilisateur,   connaissent leurs identifiants. &\\
   & \textbf{Scénario nominal} & \begin{itemize}
    \item Le système affiche le formulaire d’authentification.
\item  L’utilisateur saisit son identifiant et son mot de passe puis valide.
\item Le système vérifie l’existence des champs saisis dans
la base de données et affiche la page d’accueil.

\end{itemize}      &  \\
     & \textbf{Post condition(s)} & L’utilisateur est connecté et redirigé vers la page d’accueil qui lui correspond. & \\
    &\textbf{Exception(s)} & \begin{itemize}

  \item \textbf{ [Exception1 : champs login et/ou mot de passe vides] }   ~\par 
Le système indique à l’utilisateur de saisir une autre fois ses données.
 \item \textbf{  [Exception 2 : login et/ou mot de passe incorrects] } ~\par 
1. Les informations saisies sont fausses.
 2. Le système redirige l’utilisateur à une page d’accès interdit.
\item  \textbf{ [Exception 3 :L’utilisateur est bloqué] } ~\par 
     Le système redirige l’utilisateur à une page d’accès interdit.
\item  \textbf{  [Exception 4 :l’utilisateur est non crée]} é\par 
     L’utilisateur n’existe pas dans la base des données
     Le système redirige l’utilisateur à une page d’accès interdit.
     \end{itemize}   &
\\
   &\textbf{Maquette}&  \begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{images/UCgeneral.jpg} 
\captionof{figure}{Diagramme des cas d'utilisation globale}
\end{center} &
\end{tabu} 

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

could some one help me please .?

Comment: If you use the `tabu` package, you have to use the `longtabu` environment in addition to `longtable` to get long tables. Your MWE is kind of a mess.  See _What makes a good MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/90087

Comment: If you use LaTeX, you must use `\documentclass{<class>}` before the first `\usepackage{}`.